# Compile time error for setServiceAccount() with FirebaseOptions.Builder()

Tags: android, gradle, firebase

I was working my Android app for sending push notifications using Firebase cloud messaging. I was  setting up my server referring the guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#prerequisites.

My project level build.gradle is like :

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

App level build.grade :

```
dependencies {   
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'com.firebase:geofire:1.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
```

}

I have created the service account credentials on the console as well but while I am initializing the SDK referring https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_the_sdk

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setServiceAccount
(new  FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"))
.setDatabaseUrl("https://databaseName.firebaseio.com/")
.build();
```

I am getting compile  Error:(116, 21) error: cannot find symbol method setServiceAccount(FileInputStream)

I have checked many places but I am unable to find what I am doing wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In your server project you need to use only the dependency:
`com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)` and remove:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
```

The first is a server sdk while the others are client sdk and they will have conflicts if you try to use them together.

Comment: But I need to use google play services `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'` and `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'` at least for google play services and firebase cloud messaging.
Also as per my comment above, if I remove `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'` and use `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0` I get the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: You should do two different projects, one for the server and one for the client. In the server project you should not use client-side libraries.

Comment: Now I got it @Diego, this would be thing I would be doing wrong. I am really mixing the two things here and hence this issue. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: you are welcome. if this solves your question please accept the answer, so the question is marked as answered.

Comment: I don't think you need 15 reputation points to accept answers.
see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You're including a different version of the Firebase Database SDK than what you have for the other Firebase features:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

If you change it to:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
```

It will work better.

For more information, see the [Firebase documentation for Android developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/), from where I copied the line above.

Comment: Thanks Frank for the reply. But I am still getting the unresolved symbol error. I am calling this line of code in my MainActivity.

Comment: And if I remove 'compile  
      'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2' and use    'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
 
I get the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzbu(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate

Comment: That is correct behavior. You'll need to use the API for the 9.x version of the Firebase Android SDK. But mixing versions won't work. You should also remove `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)'`

Comment: then how should I handle my app crash because of NoSuchMethodError. And as per [add server config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) this is a required dependency as well.

Comment: I get the impression that you're trying to send push notifications from an Android client to other Android/iOS user's devices. That is not an option. Sending downstream notifications should be done from a server. Receiving downstream notifications should be done on a client. Don't mix the two.

Comment: I think that is what I am doing wrong. I should maintain separate module one for the client app and another for my app server.Thanks @Frank for the suggestion.