# Missing .setServiceAccount Method with Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to use Firebase and I have been having trouble trying to set up the server.

While following the documentation I stumbled upon this bit of code.

```
 FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
 .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/ serviceAccountCredentials.json"))
 .setDatabaseUrl("https://databaseName.firebaseio.com/")
 .build();

  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

My problem is, it seems the setServiceAccount method is not supported, because I'm getting an error in the IDE informing me that the method is an error. Going to the Firebase documentation, there does not seem to be a method called .setServiceAccount. A similar issue happens with the initializeApp method, were there seems to be an error with the argument options.

There seems to be a similar topic here.
[Compile time error for setServiceAccount() with FirebaseOptions.Builder()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497219/compile-time-error-for-setserviceaccount-with-firebaseoptions-builder)

but one of the user recommends to remove the 
          compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)'
command from the build.grade. Unfortunately for me the problem still persists. What could be the problem?

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.1'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use only the `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)'` dependency and remove:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.1'
```

The first is a server sdk while the others are client sdk and they will have conflict if you try to use them together.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, the problem still persists.  I recently removed the suggested items and was left with                                                                                                                        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)'

Comment: have you tried to run gradle sync, or just compile (with that line commented) to help the IDE updating its cache?

Comment: Yes, I clicked on sync with those two lines. I do not understand when you say "compile (with that line commented )". From the looks of it, it seems setServiceAccount is no longer supported as, I do not see it in the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder#public-constructor-summary

Comment: I checked and using only the server-side dependency works for me.  
see: https://gist.github.com/ogeidix/c6c8c154d228fa53c9e9385058c6e9a0

Comment: Keep getting an error stating Error:(29, 0) For input string: "[3". I also have     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'   inside the dependencies section.  Even with everything removed I still get the same error message. I also have apply plugin: 'com.android.application' at the top and apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the very bottom.

Comment: Why do you need those dependencies and plugins in your server-side project? Those are libraries for the application. The server-side project should not have them. In particular I think the issue is caused by "apply plugin: com.google.gms.google-services". But in general all those dependencies should not be part of the server project.